# Excel crashing without error when form.Controls.Add is called

Tags: excel, vba

Excel 2016 *version 1811 (build 11029.20079 Click-to-Run)* is crashing without error when the following code is called from a user's interaction with a UserForm. Thing is, it only crashes in THIS `(main)` UserForm. If I add the container to any other UserForm it executes without any issue.

```
Private container As Object

'***************************************************************************
'Purpose: Create the container frame that holds the page title and preview image
'***************************************************************************
Private Sub createContainer()
    Set container = main.pageThumbnails.Controls.add("Forms.Frame.1", name) ' Break here, continuing causes *CRASH*

    With container
        .Caption = ""

        .height = containerHeight
        .width = containerWidth
        .Left = 12
        .top = areaHeight

        .BackColor = defaultBackColor
        .BorderColor = defaultBorderColor
    End With

    With main.pageThumbnails
        .ScrollHeight = areaHeight
    End With

End Sub
```

Checking Windows Event Viewer gives me the following:

```
Faulting application name: EXCEL.EXE, version: 16.0.11029.20079, time stamp: 0x5bf4c8c3
Faulting module name: coml2.dll, version: 10.0.17134.407, time stamp: 0xaad4943a
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0000000000016521
Faulting process id: 0x100788
Faulting application start time: 0x01d48cb0460efe6f
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\coml2.dll
Report Id: 3ff6565e-7c37-4733-87fd-7e5ab12cba1f
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Things I've tried:

1. Running in compatibility mode (Windows 7 and 8)
2. Moving the file from a network location to my Downloads folder on the local machine
3. Casting `container` as an `MSForms.frame` instead of an `Object`
4. Restarting the computer and Excel
5. Running Excel in safe mode: `excel.exe /s`
6. Changing `container` from **Private** to **Public** and referencing `Me.container`
7. Tried each (and every) method provided by Microsoft [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53637199/excel-crashing-without-error-when-form-controls-add-is-called)
8. Installed the [KB4011128](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4011128/may-23-2018-update-for-office-2016-kb4011128) update from Microsoft. *It detected an issue and "fixed it" but the problem remains*
9. Redditors [suggested](https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/8cx7x1/april_office_updates_kb_4018319office_2016_and_kb/) that uninstalling update 4018319 could fix the issue but I don't have it installed.
10. Referencing the `main` form using a singleton module instead of `main.thumbnails`
11. Creating the frame on the `main` form code-behind
12. Referencing the created frame from a singleton module
13. Created a new `.xlsm` file, copied over all class, modules, and forms (except `main`). Created `main` from scratch
14. Added a newly created `CommandButton` to the frame **(this worked...)**
15. Changed the Id of `thumbs` frame to a bunch of random letters

Comment: Some more information on the crashing coml2.dll: https://windows10dll.nirsoft.net/coml2_dll.html

Comment: Is that code in the form's code-behind? If so, avoid referring to the form's default instance (conveniently called `main`, just like the form's class name) in the form's code-behind. Use `Me` to refer to *the current instance*, and don't store state in forms' default instance.

Comment: Adding controls at run-time to the default instance of the form could have corrupted it. Try rebuilding it from scratch.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon The code resides in a separate Controller I created to generate 'thumbnails'. It is not executed until the user clicks a checkbox.

Comment: @L8n Thank you, though it didn't help me diagnose the issue; it did help me understand the dll's purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Throughout my searching I found other people with the same crash and error logs in Windows Event Viewer. None of those posts were using VBA as I was. <s>I solved the issue by deleting the referenced Control `main.pageThumbnails` and recreating it in the editor.</s>

At this time I have no idea what caused the issue nor if this solution is permanent.

---

## Update 30 Jan 2019

After continuing to struggle with this issue and not coming up with a final solution or even an explanation as to why it's happening I created a workaround.

Instead of adding a `MSForms.Frame` object to the container I instead added the frame contents (an image and four labels) to the container and control their positioning via a `Sub setTop` method.

At this moment I'm unsure of the performance impact but at least I'm able to continue working on additional functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Is `pageThumbnails` also a frame? And do you have other containers in your userform? If so, this is an Excel bug.

This is an old question but I've just spent hours trying to find a solution so here are my findings.

First, to replicate the issue:

- Create a new UserForm (UserForm1)
- Add a Frame (FrameA)
- Add this code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    Set b = FrameA.Controls.Add("Forms.Frame.1", "FrameB")
End Sub
```

- Add a module (Module1) with:

```
Sub showUserForm1()
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

- Run showUserForm1

Everything works fine. Now add a second Frame (FrameC) along with this code in UserForm_Activate(): `Set d = FrameC.Controls.Add("Forms.Frame.1", "FrameD")`. Run showUserForm1 again: Excel crashes. More precisely, it crashes on the first line (if you skip it, the second line works fine).

After further testings, it appears that it fails only if the frame you are trying to add another frame in is at the back. If you bring successively FrameA or Frame C at the front you will notice that it fails always on the Frame wich is at the back.

So I can think of only 3 possibilities:

- don't use frames and place your controls directly in the UserForm as the OP suggested,
- make sure your frame is at the top in design mode (using Zorder does not work),
- if you can't have your frame at the top (e.g. multiple frames), try by creating them all at runtime (FrameA and FrameB within, then FrameC and FrameD within etc).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, in case anyone comes across this in future, my fix was to recreate the Control in the user form and delete the old one, it then worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. A frame, veiw from now on, on the userform that I, with code, want to add multiple frames to due to the requierments of multiple Radiobutton (optionbutton).

My solution was that I need to have a frame already placed in the view, before runing the code, for it to work. Every try were the frame was not in the view would cause Excel to crash and when it is in the view it works.

From looking at the Overwatch Window there might be an issue with the frame.controls collection as it says the Object type can not be interputated.

Edit:
Althou not thoroughly tested it seems that the "preplace frame" needs to have the same collection of controls as the frame one wishs to add